# How do I make it so that it doesn't iterate the same dictionary in the list multiple times?

Tags: python, arrays, json

This code seems to append the same dictionary multiple times

```
url = "https://api.henrikdev.xyz/valorant/v3/matches/eu/shaun/6969?filter=competitive"
r = requests.get(url).json()
red = []
blue = []
final = {}
temp = {}
for i in range(0,10):
    team = r['data'][0]['players']['all_players'][i]['team']
    player = r['data'][0]['players']['all_players'][i]['name']
    stats = r['data'][0]['players']['all_players'][i]['stats']
    char = r['data'][0]['players']['all_players'][i]['character']
    temp['team'] = team
    temp['player'] = player
    temp['stats']= stats
    temp['char'] = char
    if temp['team'] == "Red":
        red.append(temp)
        print(red)  
    elif temp['team'] == "Blue":
        blue.append(temp)
    final["blue"] = blue
    final['red']= red
```

Output:

```
[{'team': 'Red', 'player': 'TheObnoxious', 'stats': {'score': 2734, 'kills': 10, 'deaths': 20, 'assists': 3}, 'char': 'Omen'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'TheObnoxious', 'stats': {'score': 2734, 'kills': 10, 'deaths': 20, 'assists': 3}, 'char': 'Omen'}]
[{'team': 'Red', 'player': 'Djcena', 'stats': {'score': 5476, 'kills': 17, 'deaths': 18, 'assists': 7}, 'char': 'Killjoy'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'Djcena', 'stats': {'score': 5476, 'kills': 17, 'deaths': 18, 'assists': 7}, 'char': 'Killjoy'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'Djcena', 'stats': {'score': 5476, 'kills': 17, 'deaths': 18, 'assists': 7}, 'char': 'Killjoy'}]
[{'team': 'Red', 'player': 'HYDRAGOB', 'stats': {'score': 2577, 'kills': 8, 'deaths': 21, 'assists': 5}, 'char': 'Reyna'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'HYDRAGOB', 'stats': {'score': 2577, 'kills': 8, 'deaths': 21, 'assists': 5}, 'char': 'Reyna'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'HYDRAGOB', 'stats': {'score': 2577, 'kills': 8, 'deaths': 21, 'assists': 5}, 'char': 'Reyna'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'HYDRAGOB', 'stats': {'score': 2577, 'kills': 8, 'deaths': 21, 'assists': 5}, 'char': 'Reyna'}]
[{'team': 'Red', 'player': 'JOD Sauvage', 'stats': {'score': 7932, 'kills': 26, 'deaths': 19, 'assists': 11}, 'char': 'KAY/O'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'JOD Sauvage', 'stats': {'score': 7932, 'kills': 26, 'deaths': 19, 'assists': 11}, 'char': 'KAY/O'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'JOD Sauvage', 'stats': {'score': 7932, 'kills': 26, 'deaths': 19, 'assists': 11}, 'char': 'KAY/O'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'JOD Sauvage', 'stats': {'score': 7932, 'kills': 26, 'deaths': 19, 'assists': 11}, 'char': 'KAY/O'}, {'team': 'Red', 'player': 'JOD Sauvage', 'stats': {'score': 7932, 'kills': 26, 'deaths': 19, 'assists': 11}, 'char': 'KAY/O'}
```

It seems to be overwriting the previous data, I'm confused as to why this is happening

Comment: You should initialize `temp` inside the for-loop.

Comment: Hopefully this explanation is simple enough: every individual object needs to be separately created by your code. `x = {}; y = x` only makes 1 `{}` and assigns 2 names `x` and `y` to it. Likewise, you only make `temp = {}` once before the loop; you append the same `temp` dictionary over and over to `red` and `blue`, and all your modifications happen to the same `temp` dictionary. If you intended to make a *copy* each iteration and modify that, you need to use `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

1. `temp = {}` creates a reference to the dictionary
2. Inside for loop: you are populating `temp` and appending to `red` which appends a reference to the original `dictionary`.
3. Since 2nd iteration: each time you repopulate the `temp`, the previously appended `temp` references also reflect the new value along with the newly appended value.
4. It's better to avoid the declaration of temp outside of `for loop` unless its required for further calculation.
5. In such cases you can append a copy to `red` like
   `red.append(temp.copy())`